# How to store checkboxes states in session?

Tags: php, session, checkbox

Here is my code

```
<table class='block'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class='c1' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox1'>
        <label>checkbox1</label>
      </td>
    <td>
      <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox2'>
        <label>checkbox2</label>
      </td>
    <td>
      <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox3'>
        <label>checkbox3</label>
      </td>
    <td>
      <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox4'>
        <label>checkbox4</label>
      </td>
    <td>
      <input class='c3' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox5'>
        <label>checkbox5</label>
      </td>
    <td>
      <input class='c3' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox6'>
        <label>checkbox6</label>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (){
  if (this.checked) {
  var x = $(this).attr('lid');
  }
  });
</script>
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            session_start();
        }
    if(!isset($_GET['x'])) $_GET['x'] = '';
    $_SESSION['x'] = $_GET['x'];
 ?>
```

I want to save selected checkboxes in a session. So that, when I come back to the page, the same checkboxes should remain selected.

Comment: Why do you inputs not have a name attribute?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something... How are you setting $_GET['x']? That javascript is not going to make a GET request without an ajax call.

Comment: @user1885099 Then how are you submitting the data back to the page via the query string?

Comment: I am passing the data through a jquery .post

Comment: @user1885099 Could you please include the post back code along with how you are checking the session content in your post.

Comment: @user1885099 please check my answer and let me know as soon as possible. So that, i can make change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, rather than saving them into the session, save them in database. And when you came back on same page, retrieve the value from database. And i believe, it would be much easier and best approach.

**Solution of your problem**

First, you need to be sure, whether your data/checkbox value is being saved into session variable or not. Since, after going through your code-snippet, i really doubt that, your checkbox value would be saved in session variable.

**Problem 1 : You are not using GET method to store value into Session variable**

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
        {
            session_start();
        }
    if(!isset($_GET['x'])) $_GET['x'] = '';
    $_SESSION['x'] = $_GET['x'];  //  storing data using GET method
 ?>
```

This is your code, where you are trying to store data in session variable using **GET** method. But, i didn't find any `form` by which you are passing the selected value.

**Problem 2 : You are not retrieving Session variable**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (){
  if (this.checked) {
  var x = $(this).attr('lid');
  }
  });
</script>
```

In your `javascript` code, you didn't mention any session variable, by which, you can match the previous checked variable.

Comment: I use this: location.href = 'target.php?x='+x; I forgot to add it in the striped code I posted.

Comment: through any link/button ??

Comment: then after clicking on that button, check on your URL, what value it is showing there.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Here is a working example of what your trying to accomplish using a session.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['checkbox']))
{
    $_SESSION[$_GET['checkbox'][0]] = isset($_SESSION[$_GET['checkbox'][0]]) ? +!($_SESSION[$_GET['checkbox'][0]]) : TRUE;
    print_r($_SESSION[$_GET['checkbox'][0]]);
    die;
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class='block'>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c1' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox1' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox1'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox1</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox2' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox2'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox2</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox3' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox3'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox3</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c2' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox4' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox4'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox4</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c3' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox5' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox5'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox5</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input class='c3' type='checkbox' lid='checkbox6' <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['checkbox6'])) ? 'CHECKED="CHECKED"' : ''; ?>><label>checkbox6</label>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table> 
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
           $.get("sefesf.php", { 'checkbox[]':$(this).attr('lid') });
       }) 
    });
</script>
```

**The Skinny**

Basically, each time you check a box a GET request is made to itself and does +! on the session. Which means the opposite of. So it will automatically check and uncheck the session variable. The request is done asyncronously with AJAX and stores the data. The CHECK feature is done server side with PHP on page load with a simple ternary operator in the DOM.

**To Do**

Make sure you add some validation on the _GET, you dont want to be storing erraneous data.

Also, this is a pretty dirty way to do this type of thing, but a way none-the-less.

Good luck, let me know if you have questions!