# Redirect without HEADER() in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have the following code in PHP:

```
header ("Location: nopass.php?percent=$percentage&type=$type");
```

The form page has radio buttons which will reset to default if I go back because I am changing the page using `header();`

I thought using Javascript to go back would fix the issue:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">Go Back</a>
```

But it didn't.

Is there any workaround for the header(); to redirect without writing the header?

I am using POST method for my form.

Comment: Using `POST` will make the previous request discarded right?

Comment: I did create a test page to see that and it doesn't unless I am wrong.

Comment: Example: http://www.interfaithmedical.com/checksite/testFolder/a.htm (I used POST method) try and fill out all radio button and hit submit and then press the "go back" on the next page and it keeps the radio button state.

Comment: @SiKni8: You should simply make the form page remember the choices from the previous request (session variables are the easiest way to do that) and just let `header` be. If you don't do that, *any* kind of redirection will wipe the values out.

Comment: @Jon How would that be accomplished without taking too much of your time.

Comment: @SiKni8: Very roughly [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13991500/50079), although of course the code can be made much more concise.

Comment: Just use session to save those values

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im How would I use that session when the "back" button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your form information inside the $_SESSION, and check for this information when creating the form on your page. A rudimentary example would be to:

form.php:

```
<?php session_start(); //Start the Session ?>
<input type="radio" name="radios" value="value1" <?php
    /* Check if we've been submitted before */
    if (isset($_SESSION['last_submit']['radios']) && "value1" == $_SESSION['last_submit']['radios']) {
        echo "selected";
    }
?> > Value 1 </input> "
/.. more inputs ../
```

and in submit.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION[last_submit] = (!empty($_POST)) ? $_POST : array();
```

Obviously, you would want to filter the POST for any XSS, identify your form so that you don't accidently pre-populate other forms, and clear the info on success, but this should give you a rough idea.

Comment: That sounds like a great way, but would need a little more detailed code... Tll the POST are radio buttons with the exception of a few textboxes which I will use to filter out for any XSS attack. Thanks

Comment: @SiKni8 Please be aware that the fact that an input field is presented in HTML as a radio button is **not** protection against somebody putting bogus data into that variable. It is entirely trivial to write a page (or edit using debug tools in the browser) that submits arbitrary text where you are expecting the fixed value of a radio button.

Comment: @IMSoP is absolutely right -- you should always treat any GET/POST variables as potentially being unsafe and should either filter them as if they were a text box, or use string matching to reject any unexpected values.

Comment: Great Point... I will modify based on your feedback

Comment: So something like this in my PHP page `"q1" => $_POST['S1Q1'];` should be changed to `"q1" => trim(strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['S1Q1'])));` for better security?

Comment: @SiKni8 No. You should do *appropriate* escaping *when you use the variable*. When you output a variable to an HTML context, use `htmlspecialchars()` or `html_entities()`; when you use it in an SQL context, use the appropriate SQL escaping function (e.g. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`) or pass it as a parameter to a prepared query; etc. The only thing you can do generically when you *receive* the string is completely rejecting strings in the wrong format based on a very restrictive whitelist (*not* a blacklist), or converting to integer or float.

Comment: This would be a good start, but you should consider the use of [Data Filtering](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) for Sanitization and Validation. @SiKni8's recommendations for the use of the data after filtering and use of a whitelist for radios provide additional protections.

Comment: I am not as versatile in PHP, so is `"q1" => htmlspecialchars($_POST['S1Q1'])` suite better? For now I am not doing anything in SQL as my server is not upto date with the version.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour of retaining the contents of the form is a convenience facility provided by the browser, and not to do with HTTP *per se*.

When you use the PHP `header()` function to redirect, you make the page return an HTTP status of `301` or `302`, which tells the browser to load the other URL instead.

The difference with the Javascript `history.back()` method is that you are not giving a URL, you are specifically telling the browser to take a step back through its history, just as though the user had clicked the "back" button in the toolbar. The browser is then making the decision that the form should be rendered as it was when the user left that page.

AFAIK, there is no way in HTTP of telling a User-Agent to go back in its history, because "history" is not a concept defined in raw HTTP (it is an explicitly stateless protocol). Consequently, only client-side code, i.e. Javascript, will trigger that behaviour.

Rather than trying to change the way the redirect is working, why not make it so that no redirect happens at all, and the form is simply re-displayed with the user's selections pre-populated. That way you are not relying on any particular browser behaviour.

This doesn't need to have any complex session storage, as the values will be in `$_POST` already, so you can just render your form elements with like `<input name="foo" value="x" <?php if ( $_POST['foo'] == 'x' ) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>`. This is a common way of re-displaying a form after form validation.

Answer (score 1):

This will redirect in any case, whether headers are sent or not.

```
function redirect($url)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
    {
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: so will this keep the headers active?

Comment: this will let you to redirect to certain URL. To preserve values as you asked, you must use session.

Comment: So even UL redirect will not keep the session alive? So how is this working? (Example: interfaithmedical.com/checksite/testFolder/a.htm (I used POST method) try and fill out all radio button and hit submit and then press the "go back" on the next page and it keeps the radio button state.)

Comment: This is not relevant to the question - the OP's problem is not that the redirect is failing, but that the browser is not remembering the form state when it redirects to a previously completed form.